# Uploading files over WCF using "content-type" encoding

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, content-type

I would like to upload GZIP files over WCF.
Doing so I would like to use some sort of additional parameter such as "HTTP content encoding" to tell the server what to do with a certain file type.

I am already using mimeType to tag the actual file, but in some cases (file size) I need to ZIP the file and send it over. Doing so i would like to tag this action using proper and valid parameter.

PS: The actual file is being send as byte[].

Can someone give me an example of doing this the proper way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by sending string over to the server. On the server I created ENUM with acceptable values.